# $a^2 \equiv b^2$ mod 4 equivalence classes.

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

so we have the relation $a^2 \equiv b^2$ mod 4. And to find equivalence classes we say b or a = 0 so $a^2=4k$ so $a=+-2\sqrt{k} $ so all even numbers. But when we get to a=1 then $a^2=4k+1$ after plugging stuff in i see it is all the odd numbers, but how to prove it? Thanks in advance. Keep in mind i do not want to check if it is true for odd/even i want to prove it form zero.

Comment: $a^2\equiv b^2\pmod{4}$ iff $a\equiv b\pmod{2}$ has a quick proof.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I can see the proof for the reverse implication but not for the forward one ;/

Comment: If $4$ divides $(a-b)(a+b)$, then $2$ divides $a-b$ or $a+b$. If it divides $a-b$ we are finished.  If it divides $a+b$, then since $a-b=a+b-2b$, it divides $a-b$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas oh right, thanks ^^. But it seems like i have to know that for it to work. i have to know it will be either odd or even. But how do i do it without knowing a single thing

Comment: It is better to work with odd and even, show any two even are equivalent, any two odd are equivalent, and no odd iis equivalent to an even. For this it is enough to show that $0$ is not equivalent to $1$. As to your wish to avoid mentioning odd and even, why not introduce them, prove the basic properties?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Well yeah but things are simple here, lets say a^3 congruent b^3 mod 4. I have classes [0]=2k,[1]=4k+1,[2]=4k+2,[3]=4k+3. It is not as simple, here you cannot say all odd are equal. So i am looking for some general tips for this stuff. Here i used the (x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2) it was annoying but worked.

Answer (score 1):

whatever the parity of $a$ and $b$ we have $a-b=(a+b)-2b$ this shows that
$$
2|(a+b) \Leftarrow\Rightarrow 2|(a-b) \tag{1}
$$
keeping this in mind throughout, we notice that if
$$
a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod 4
$$
then
$$
4|(a^2-b^2)=(a+b)(a-b)
$$
from which
$$
2|(a-b)
$$
or
$$
a \equiv b \mod 2
$$

given (1), these steps are reversible